# ipad - How can I control the version of my iPad app?

Tags: ipad, version

I am not talking about the formal version control (svn, etc) for my iPad app.

I wish someone could tell me where in my app to set the version of the app.

For example, my app's product name is Go Here. To indicate the version, where should i set the version? bundle version in the plist? I need this version thing just in case that in the future, if I update the app store for newer version, people can download and update.

Should I modify the bundle version in the plist, but keep the product name and target name the same? If I make a newer version, I just update the bundle version only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to edit the "Bundle Version" (CFBundleVersion) in your Info.plist. That's it.

BTW, haven't tested, but you should be able to get the version at runtime with this:

```
versionString = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. But it seems that when I send this to someone for beta test (I took the steps of the formal app beta test procedure), that guy can install my app through iTune without problem for the first time. For the following times, even if I update the bundle version to higher, and gave it to that guy, he could not successfully installed. iTune said it was updating but actually the app remains the old version.